# using a variable in two tex documents

Tags: macros

I have a file named "main" and other name "other" and I want input data in main file and these data will be processed by external, for example:

file main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\def\name#1

\begin{document}
\name{Andrey}
\input{other} 

\end{document}
```

file other.tex

```
my name is \textbf{\name}
```

Where the output will be:

my name is **Andrey**

all this is for maketitle with this code

Comment: `\def\name#1` is a syntax error I guess you meant `\def\name{Audrey}` (or better `\newcommand\name{Audrey}` either way the use in your second file would then work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In a strict sense, `\def\name#1...{document}` is not a syntax error. The parameter text is a little unusual and very likely not intended. The definition of `\name` is `macro:#1 \par \begin ->document`. The syntax error is then the usage of `\name{Andrey}`. `#1` is present, also the space by the line end. But token `\par` is missing.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I know (and I know you know) but.... :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek there is a `\par` (the empty line after `\input{other}`). I think `\begin` is missing.

Comment: @Skillmon The space after `#1` (`{Andrey}`) must be immediately followed by `\par`.  Other tokens are not allowed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that you know and had up-voted the comment, but writing packages without bugs sets a high standard. :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek there is the space after `\input{other}`. `\name` would grab `{Andrey} \input {other}` as its argument. Then there is a space and a `\par`. The problem is the missing `\begin`. Add a `\begin` just before `\end{document}` and you'll see.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, you are right, I was too hasty. `\begin` is missing after `\par`. And a later `\begin` would not match because `#1` is not allowed to contain `\par`.